# Removing duplicates from two lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have written some code in python to remove duplicate items from lists. I have two separate lists that look like:

```
lhsNet = ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', '(2)H', 'p', '(2)H', 'p', '(3)He', '(3)He']

rhsNet = ['(2)H', 'e+', 'nu_e', '(2)H', 'e+', 'nu_e', '(3)He', 'gamma', '(3)He', 'gamma', '(4)He', 'p', 'p']
```

Here is the code:

```
for x in lhsNet:
    for z in rhsNet:
        if x == z:
            lhsNet.remove(x)
            rhsNet.remove(z)
            break
```

The code should find a duplicate entry that exists in both lists and remove it. For some reason after execution I am left with:

```
lhsNet = ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', '(3)He']

rhsNet = ['e+', 'nu_e', 'e+', 'nu_e', 'gamma', '(3)He', 'gamma', '(4)He']
```

Clearly it has removed all of the duplicate entries that exist in both lists EXCEPT for the last `'(3)He'`. Can anyone explain to me what is going wrong in my code and how to fix it?

Comment: Order is not important.

Comment: I think I may have actually just fixed it... I took out the break and it seems to work now.. any idea why that may be?

Comment: It's just how your code works. There is not really a lot to explain. Also take a look into the edit of my post, because your way of doing it is a non-pythonic way.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot man. By the way this might sound stupid but... Why is it better to be "pythonic"? My professor always stresses it but has never explained why.

Comment: Because it's just the way how Python works. If you want to program in a C-style, use C. A pythonic way is usually way more easier to read and normally more efficient since Python is designed to be used like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use break statement when you iterate
If you just remove it and make your code look like.

```
    for x in lhsNet:
        for z in rhsNet:
            if x == z:
               lhsNet.remove(x)
               rhsNet.remove(z)
```

Everything will be working perfectly

Answer (score 4):

I think that should work out for you:

```
new_lhsNet = list(set(lhsNet) - set(rhs_net))
new_rhsNet = list(set(rhsNet) - set(lhsNet))
```

Edit:
Otherwise you can try the following as well:

```
lhsNet = [x for x in lhsNet if not x in rhsNet]
rhsNet = [x for x in rhsNet if not x in lhsNet]
```

The *set()* method from the upper example removes every duplicate within the list itself, which is probably not what you want. The lower example removes only the duplicates from another list without the duplicates within the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `break` statement and it will work as you want.

Comment: OP already knows it. check the comments. You should explain why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Once the data is matched with rhsNet,the inner loop will break,it will not iterate through entire  data of rhsNet list. So, Please remove the break statement in the code and able to get the unique values in both list.